# How can I expand a snippet within a snippet using YASnippet?

Tags: emacs, code-snippets, yasnippet

At the [YASnippet](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-reference.html#yas-triggers-in-field) site I noticed the following description of `yas/triggers-in-field` :

> If non-nil, `yas/next-field-key` can trigger stacked expansions, that is
> a snippet expansion inside another snippet expansion. Otherwise,
> `yas/next-field-key` just tries to move on to the next field.

I'm not clear how to make this happen.

I assumed that after I set: `#expand-env: ((yas/triggers-in-field #t))`, whenever I typed an abbrev in a field and pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> it would expand, however that's not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`yas/triggers-in-field` is a variable. Per default it is set to nil.

Its docstring says:

> If non-nil, `yas/next-field-key' can trigger stacked expansions.
>
> Otherwise, `yas/next-field-key' just tries to move on to the next
> field

Thus, to enable stacked expansions you have to set the variable to a non-nil value such as `t`. If you want this setting permanent put the following in your .emacs:

```lisp
(setq yas/triggers-in-field t); Enable nested triggering of snippets
```

You can read about [other customizable YASnippet variables](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-reference.html#orgfd54294)