# How to programmatically include yasnippet snippets in a snippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I'm looking for a way to write a snippet that would let me include another snippet. Here is an example of a snippet for a python function:

```
def test(args):
    ${1:code here}
    $(insert-snippet "not_implemented_exception")
```

In the example, I would like to first write some contents to the python function in field #1, then hit TAB. Hitting TAB should take me to the lisp bit, where I may choose to expand the snippet with the name "not_implemented_exception".

I tried reading the source code but am very new to lisp, so I found nothing of use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I expand a snippet within a snippet using YASnippet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556922/how-can-i-expand-a-snippet-within-a-snippet-using-yasnippet)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just make the text "not_implemented_exception" the last tabstop, so you can press TAB one more time to expand it.

```
def test(args):
    ${1:code here}
    not_implemented_exception$0
```

In case you don't want to put the snippet at the end, you can enable nested snippet by

```
(setq yas-triggers-in-field t)
```

Comment: Seems to work, with a limitation that it only works for the last field. I tried changing the last line to ${2:not_implemented_exception$3} but yas-next-field does not expand my exception snippet. I wonder what could be wrong.

Comment: There's some change in yasnippet recently, you should try `yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand` (with `yas-triggers-in-field` on) instead

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your comment through. If you want to make `not_implemented_exception` a place holder it needs to be `${2:not_implemented_exception$0}`. Tab stop `$0` will exit the first snippet so it can expand the next one.
If you want to use stacked snippet expand then see my previous comment. Personally I find it confusing so I don't use it.

Comment: `yas-triggers-in-field` is set to `t`, but `yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand` still jumps to the next snippet when applied with `${2:not_implemented_exception$3}`. This happens at field #3. Could this be a misconfiguration? Here is all my [config](http://hpaste.org/77952) on yasnippet.

Comment: It could be a bug or something, you can try contact the author on Github. Honestly I used this feature only a few times before.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try asking the author on Github.