# How to make auto-complete work with yasnippet and abbrev?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, key-bindings, yasnippet

I want Emacs to work like this:

- Let `auto-complete` auto-popup menu:

  ```
  (setq ac-auto-show-menu 0.8)
  (setq ac-delay 0.1)
  ```
- Use <kbd>C-n/p</kbd> / <kbd>M-n/p</kbd> to select `auto-complete` popup menu candidates:

  ```
  (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "M-n") 'ac-next)
  (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "M-p") 'ac-previous)
  ```
- When *selecting* a candiate

  - disable <kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>S-TAB</kbd> in popup menu selection:

    ```
    (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
    (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "<S-tab>") nil)
    ```
  - press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the candiate, without inserting *newline*:

    ```
    ;; ???
    ```
  - if the candidate is an *abbrev*, <kbd>Enter</kbd> should only select the candiate:

    ```
    ;; ???
    ```

    ... and pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> should cause Emacs to auto-expand the abbrev.
  - if the candidate is a *dabbrev*, pressing <kbd>M-\</kbd> on candidate should trigger `dabbrev-expand`.
  - pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>C-i</kbd> to expand the candidate for `yasnippet`:

    ```
    (setq yas-trigger-key "TAB")
    ```

    I set this, but the trigger does not expand when I press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
  - pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> to expand a snippet trigger while in a field:

    ```
    (setq yas-triggers-in-field t)
    ```
  - pressing <kbd>C-j</kbd> to jump to next field:

    ```
    (setq yas-next-field-key '("<tab>")) ;; or "C-j"
    ```
  - [How can I expand a snippet within a snippet using `yasnippet`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556922/how-can-i-expand-a-snippet-within-a-snippet-using-yasnippet)

---

#### Some explanations

There are two <kbd>TAB</kbd>s in Emacs:

- `(kbd "TAB")` / `(\t, [9])`
- `(kbd "<tab>")` / `([tab])`

If modes like `yasnippet` and `auto-complete` want to bind to <kbd>TAB</kbd>, their trigger key must be the same as the original tab command. Since Emacs binds `indent-for-tab-command` to `(kbd "TAB")`, it's better to use that as the trigger key. `yasnippet` binds to it by default, and it is easy to set up `auto-complete` to trigger using <kbd>TAB</kbd> as well:

```
;; trigger using TAB and disable auto-start
(custom-set-variables
 '(ac-trigger-key "TAB")
 '(ac-auto-start nil)
 '(ac-use-menu-map t))
```

But in some modes (`ruby-mode`, `markdown-mode`, `org-mode`, etc.), the command is bound to
`(kbd "<tab>")`. When the real tab key is typed, the function bound to `(kbd "<tab>)` has higher priority, so `yasnippet` and `auto-complete` are not invoked. This is easy to fix by moving the key binding:

```
(defun iy-tab-noconflict ()
  (let ((command (key-binding [tab])))                 ; remember command
    (local-unset-key [tab]) ; unset from (kbd "<tab>")
    (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") command)))              ; re-bind to (kbd "TAB")
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'iy-ac-tab-noconflict)
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'iy-ac-tab-noconflict)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'iy-ac-tab-noconflict)
```

#### My setup

I downloaded `yasnippet`, `auto-complete` via the `el-get` packager manager. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Emacs 24.3.50.1.

#### Wrapping up

I know this problem is a little long, but it really makes it difficult for me to use `auto-complete` and `yasnippet`. If the basic key binding doesn't work smoothly, this slows down my workflow quite a bit. I think many people have similar problems because I found some similar questions on the internet (though none of them are exactly like mine).

As you can see above, some of the relevant settings I already know. (But if you think I made a mistake somewhere, please tell me.) There are also some things I still don't know how to set up (`???`). Maybe there isn't a way to make *all* of these settings work together? Let me know if that is the case, and otherwise please make sure none of these setting interfere with each other.

After I get the answer to this question, I hope to write an Emacs extension to initialize all of these settings automatically.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the problem you're describing a long time ago and resolved it like this:
bind `auto-complete` to <kbd>TAB</kbd> (also <kbd>C-i</kbd> which is the same)
and `yasnippet` to <kbd>C-o</kbd>.
Abbrevs are on <kbd>C-o</kbd> as well, but I don't use them a lot.

The advantages are:

1. No stateful behavior results in a much more relaxed and productive editing.
2. You no longer think "what will TAB do in this context?" before pressing,
   you just press it.
3. You no longer check if you got the expected outcome, because there's only one.
4. You can use `auto-complete` while in the process of expanding `yasnippet`.
5. <kbd>C-i</kbd> and <kbd>C-o</kbd> are neighbors and very easy to press.
6. Yasnippets now expand reliably in any mode since no mode overrides <kbd>C-o</kbd>.

This may be not what you want right now but consider trying it:
you might like it after a while.

Comment: Good Idea, I tried this before, but still try to find a solution for this, because I think <kbd>TAB</kbd> is for this action. This seems rediculous. But it did. I found <kbd>C-o</kbd> is fine. I will like it. But I still have the problem, about use [Enter] to select the candidate in auto-complete popup menu. And seems yasnippet can not work for me (this is another problem I know). I tried to use [M-x yas-expand] to expand the trigger, but it does not work too. What do you think about this problem ?

Comment: For `auto-complete` I expand always with `tab` or `C-i` never ever with `RET`.
For `yasnippet`, you can get `auto-yasnippet` from MELPA and `(global-set-key "\C-o" 'aya-open-line)`.

Comment: No, I do not want to complete with `RET`, I select condicate with `RET`. I let auto-complete auto raise popup menu. I give the `TAB` to snippet engine -> YASnippet.

Comment: As you prefer, I select candidate with `C-i`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstand my mean, I mean I use `C-n/p` or `M-n/p` to navigate in auto-complete popup menu. I want to use `RET` to *select* candidate in menu. I think you use `C-i` to enable auto-complete to raise popup menu if I have not misunderstand your words. If I want to use `C-i` to select candidate, I at least need a function to bind, what's the function to select candidate ?

Comment: I almost never navigate. I just type enough so that the candidate that I want is the
first one. Then I select it with `C-i`. It's quite productive: over time I
get an intuition of how many letters I have to type to get the candidate I want to be first.

Comment: I found the reason, I found `ac-expand` in variable `ac-menu-map`. This is what I want `RET` to map. And `tab` is bind to `ac-expand` by default, that's why I can't understand why you can select with `C-i`.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `RET` or `<return>` to function `ac-expand`. This is for select candidate.